# Returning the larger number

Tags: java

I am attempting this question and i met this error

This is a very general syntax error that may be caused by a variety of problems, such as misplaced { } braces or an incorrect sequence of Java keywords/operators. Sometimes the error is not on the line indicated but rather on a previous line.

```
illegal start of expression
if(num1>(num2+num3)) ||(num2>(num1 +num3)) || (num3 >(num1 + num2)) {
```

> Write a method dominant that accepts three integers as parameters and
>   returns true if any one of the three integers is larger than the sum
>   of the other two integers. The integers might be passed in any order,
>   so the largest value could be any of the three. If no value is larger
>   than the sum of the other two, your method should return false.
>
> For example, the call of dominant(4, 9, 2) would return true because 9
>   is larger than 4 + 2. The call of dominant(5, 3, 7) would return false
>   because none of those three numbers is larger than the sum of the
>   others. You may assume that none of the numbers is negative.

My attempt:

```
public boolean dominant(int num1,int num2,int num3){
    if(num1>(num2+num3)) ||(num2>(num1 +num3)) || (num3 >(num1 + num2)) {
        return true;

    }else{
        return false;
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're closing off the if statement `if(num1>(num2+num3))`. Try surrounding the whole thing in another set of parentheses.

```
public boolean dominant(int num1,int num2,int num3){
    if((num1>(num2+num3)) ||(num2>(num1 +num3)) || (num3 >(num1 + num2))) {
        return true;

    }else{
        return false;
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with your if (condition). You can correct it as shown below:

```
 public boolean dominant(int num1,int num2,int num3){
        if ((num1 > (num2+num3)) ||(num2 > (num1 +num3)) || (num3 > (num1 + num2))) {
            return true;

        } else { return false; }  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your brackets are misplaced:
if(num1>(num2+num3)) ||(num2>(num1 +num3)) || (num3 >(num1 + num2))

It should be:

```
if((num1>(num2+num3)) ||(num2>(num1 +num3)) || (num3 >(num1 + num2))
```